How can I start the GUI of Ubuntu (running under Windows)?
I installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS under Windows from the Microsoft Store.
There is written it contains a GUI (Graphical User Interface?).
What's the name of this GUI, and how can I start it?

Did you install "Windows Subsystem for Linux" ?  which is not Ubuntu.    Seems likely given it came from the Microsoft Store.
